# Cannot set JAVA_HOME

Tags: android, qt, android-ndk

I am currently trying to compile a qt project to run on an android tablet and the build process works as expected, but when I try to deploy it, it quits saying it can't find the javac compiler because JAVA_HOME is set to the place where the JRE resides.

I have already tried adding JAVA_HOME to the build environment in Qt Creator, then in the/etc/profile file and finally outputting the JAVA_HOME variable from the script that starts ant and they all point to the correct path.

I have also tried to grep through all the files for the JRE path string literal, but this didn't yield any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few unsuccessful attempts I found that it was in fact looking for the tools.jar file that got moved to another location in openjdk 7, even though the error messages were referring to JAVA_HOME.

I installed openjdk 6 and it works now

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to install the JDK. Just the JRE won't be enough.

This is because only the JDK has the Java compiler, JRE is just the Java Runtime Environment.

Comment: I already installed the jdk and set JAVA_HOME to point to the place where it's installed

Comment: yes, it's a symlink in the /usr/bin directory that ultimately ends to javac